# NUnit Tests are executing twise while running Testcases using Nunit TestAdapter

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

While running test cases using Nunit TestAdapter from Visual Studio 2015 each test case is executing twise. I am new to C#, Selenium and NUnit. Can any one help me to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code....

Comment: I copied same code as it is provided in this link http://relevantcodes.com/using-nunit-to-execute-selenium-webdriver-tests/

Comment: and added below references <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnitTestAdapter" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="2.47.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="2.47.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver" version="2.46.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />